# Какой выбрать язык для скриптов на C++ движок?

Tags: c++, scripts

Какой интерпретируемый или условно компилируемый язык стоит использовать/можете посоветовать, чтобы реализовать систему скриптов на самописном c++ движке? (по типу c# на Unity, Lua для Roblox и т.п.)

Я думаю про Lua, Ruby или Python ..

Comment: Тот который наиболее популярен у предполагаемых пользователей программы.

Comment: ИМХО, Lua быстр, лёгок в освоении и популярен, много уроков.

Comment: Из того что ты написал, Lua самый логичный вариант. Легко импортируется, быстро работает, отлично расширяется. А вообще по сути без разницы, хоть V8 подключай. Дело твоё )

Comment: А я бы смотрел в сторону питона или джаваскрипта. Ну, просто потому, что людей, которые думают, что знают эти языки-очень много...

Comment: Посмотрите на tcl (у него вообще есть библиотечная реализация для Си, это позволит легко сделать глубокую интеграцию)

Comment: FORTH - только хардкор

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Список встраиваемых скриптовых языков можно найти тут: [dbohdan/embedded-scripting-languages](https://github.com/dbohdan/embedded-scripting-languages).

Самый популярный встраиваемый язык - [Lua](https://www.lua.org/pil/24.html). Первый выбор если вы пишете игру. Каждый второй геймдизайнер его знает.

Если вам нужен популярный язык общего назначения - [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html). Легко изучить, легко найти программистов готовых на нём писать.

Языки (почти) без синтаксиса хорошо подходят для автоматизации, но будет трудно найти того кто будет на них писать. По первой ссылке ищите ключевые слова `Forth`, `Scheme`, `Common Lisp`.